# Not unique table/alias (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

> Error Number: 1066
>
> Not unique table/alias: 'posts'
>
> SELECT * FROM (SELECT `id`, `title`, `keywords`, 'posts' AS type FROM
>   `posts`, `posts` UNION SELECT `id`, `title`, `keywords`, 'android' AS
>   type FROM `android`, `android` UNION SELECT `id`, `title`, `keywords`,
>   'mac' AS type FROM `mac`, `mac`)t WHERE t.title like '%yj%' OR
>   t.keywords LIKE '%yj%'

model:

```
  $query = $this->input->GET('search', TRUE);
  $this->db->select("id, title, keywords, 'posts' AS type");
  $this->db->from("posts");

  $query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select('posts');

  $this->db->select("id, title, keywords, 'android' AS type");
  $this->db->from("android");

  $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select('android');

  $this->db->select("id, title, keywords, 'mac' AS type");
  $this->db->from("mac");

  $query3 = $this->db->get_compiled_select('mac');


  $data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM (' . $query1 . ' UNION ' . $query2 . ' UNION ' . $query3 . ')' . "t WHERE t.title like '%$query%' OR t.keywords LIKE '%$query%'");
         return $data->result();
```

Comment: `FROM  posts, posts` ? What do you want to do?

Comment: Like from 3 tables posts,android,mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all 2nd names of the tables and use UNION ALL instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, title, keywords, 'posts' AS type FROM  posts 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id, title, keywords, 'android' AS type FROM android 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id, title, keywords, 'mac' AS type FROM mac
)t WHERE t.title like '%yj%' OR t.keywords LIKE '%yj%'
```